# Desktop GUI Environment vs. Gaming Graphics

Tags: graphics-card, desktop, gui, gaming, aero

This quetion stems from my noticing that my Windows 7 Experience ratings for Aero Desktop Performance is significantly less than the rating for Gaming Graphics.

I built an AMD 8-core APU. The Windows 7 Experience ratings indicate that the Aero Graphics (rated at 4.9) are less than the gaming graphics (6.4). I would have thought these two functions would be handled by the same hardware. Also, I would have thought that the Aero graphics would be less intesive than gaming graphics, although the Aero is functioning all of the time.

There must be something I misunderstanding about both the Windows Experience ratings and how the APU is handling aero/desktop environment and graphics. I have read these two articles ([1](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/why-is-windows-experience-index-for-graphics-score/82b02afd-2133-4c83-b73f-b7b356eba321) and [2](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Windows-Experience-Index-Understand-and-improve-your-computers-performance-in-Windows-Vista) which are both blah) to understand the difference, **but this leads me to another question:  Is the GUI portion of the desktop environment, inlcuding muliple monitors, handled by the same hardware graphics modules as those that handle gaming and HD video?  If not, what specs affect what function graphical funcions?**

*Your answer might include explanations of how the difference specifications of a graphics card (such as onboard memory, frame rates, clock rate, memory interface [128-bit/256-bit], DirectX, etc.) affect different functions (desktop GUI environment vs. intensive gaming vs. HD media output, etc.). Thank you o' Knowledgeable Ones.

POST NOTE: I know many of the hardware specs will probably overlap, but hopefully this post will help indicate what is most important for different roles such as gaming, media center, multi-display setups (*besides* just the extra outputs), video/photo rendering, etc.

Comment: @Ramhound I know to research my question before asking, so if I didn't come upon the post I was looking for, then please point me in the right direction so that this one may be deleted. That is, if an answer to my questions exists so readily and is easy to find. Otherwise, you might provide an answer yourself if you have one.

Comment: @Ramhound -- Touché Mr. RamMan, Touché... But I highly doubt you could give me anything more than a superficial explanation. Certainly nothing technical.

Comment: @Ramhound: Please be nice. There is no need to be so condescending to newcomers.

Comment: @DragonLord - Most people overestimate their ability to understand the tone of somebody's written words.  I suggest you take that into account before you comment on my comments I have made in the past.  You are starting to question comments, unlike the comment I made in this question, that are actually trying to get more information out of the user.  You doing that makes me wonder the reason I even, tell new users, on how I believe their question could be improved upon.

Comment: @Ramhound: Look at how the OP responded to your (now deleted) comments. Is this the sort of reaction we want to see from newcomers?

Comment: @Ramhound - There are ways of expressing tone/intent in comments :-). Failing that, apologising for any misunderstanding usually goes a long way :-). user58446 - not a full answer but different Graphics cards are optimized for different things - you can get cards optimized for business (spreadsheets etc), CAD designing, gaming, and other things. That would be why your Aero rating is lower - your card wasn't built to handle it well.

Comment: Let me finish this up by apologising for any unintended rudeness. Looking back, I want to make sure @Ramhound knows that "RamMan" was meant as a portmanteau of the words "Ramhound" and "Man", nothing else that it might seem like... Honest. My question really wanted to touch on the more technical aspects of how these graphics chipsets are geared toward different tasks... such as the components listed in my original question. If this is the wrong forum for this type of question and desired answer, please let me know and we can transfer it. Thank you. Love. Peace. Harmony :)

Comment: The good ol' misinterpretation of written words type of a scenario...The proper forum for some discussions is face-to-face and eye-to-eye... see who blinks the most then... <;;::;;::;;::;;;;{[XXXX]}o